# Changing the order of reveal when using \pause

Tags: beamer, navigation, pause

I'm using "\pause" to shade some text in my presentation. However I want to reveal stuff different than the top-bottom order they appear on the slide.

I've thought about using "\only", however it doesn't exactly to what I envision, since it completely makes the text disappear at a certain, where as I want them in shaded form.

I've provided MWE below, and hopefully that makes it clear what I want to achieve.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

  \frame{\titlepage}

   \frame{
     \frametitle{some title}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 1st text to be revealed

\pause

\begin{itemize}
\item 3rd text to be revealed
\end{itemize}

\pause

\item 2nd text to be revealed

\pause

\begin{itemize}
\item 4th text to be revealed
\end{itemize}

\end{enumerate}
}
       

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not sure of what exactly you need, but here are few options:

With `\visible`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

  \frame{\titlepage}

   \frame{
     \frametitle{some title}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 1st text to be revealed

\visible<3->{\begin{itemize}
\item 3rd text to be revealed
\end{itemize}}

\visible<2->{
\item 2nd text to be revealed
}
\visible<4->{
\begin{itemize}
\item 4th text to be revealed
\end{itemize}
}

\end{enumerate}
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Or even simpler

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

  \frame{\titlepage}

   \frame{
     \frametitle{some title}

\begin{enumerate}
\item<1-> 1st text to be revealed

\begin{itemize}
\item<3-> 3rd text to be revealed
\end{itemize}

\item<2-> 2nd text to be revealed

\begin{itemize}
\item<4-> 4th text to be revealed
\end{itemize}


\end{enumerate}
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I want to do exactly what you achieve here, with one small difference. Visible completely hides the text till it's revealed. I want it to be shaded.(as in the case of \pause)

Comment: @alexT In your example code with `\pause`, the upcoming text is also completely hidden instead of shaded ;) I guess you're using `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` to achieve the shading effect; if you add this line to the preamble, the second example given in this answer yields shaded text as well, and the first one does too if you replace `\visible` by `\uncover`.